# data won't insert in database via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

Im trying to insert some text that a Label has, and it wont insert it for some reason.

this is my code :

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery1, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", UserNameOrGuest.Text);
ErrorLabel.Text = "Movie rental succeeded!";
```

the sqlquery is : `string sqlquery1 = "INSERT INTO Movies (Status) VALUES (@Status)";`

Thanks for the help

Comment: how do you create and open the connection? when do you call cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ?? can you show more code in your question?

Comment: So where is the `cmd.ExceuteNonQuery`? What exception do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the `SqlCommand` object but you are not executing the command to perform `insert` operation.  use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute the command.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery1, conn); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", UserNameOrGuest.Text); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
ErrorLabel.Text = "Movie rental succeeded!";
```

Check example here : [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) and [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> create a SqlCommand and then executes it using ExecuteNonQuery/ExecuteScaler.

Answer (score 2):

Is this your entire code? you seem to miss a call which executes the query?

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a statment?

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```